# Design pattern that pulls data instead of pushing?

Tags: design-patterns

I am learning about the observer pattern, which leads me to question is there a pattern that does the opposite. 
Where I can pull changes from a group of observable objects.

Say I have a Sudoku Puzzle, and when I enter a number, I want to confirm that no other box in the same row, column, or square has the same number.

Is there a pattern where I can configure a list of observable boxes and pull their current value?

Comment: I think it's usually called "pulling" or "polling"

Comment: Possibly something like a [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) where each box is a link in the chain and has a chance to decide whether the input number is valid. Chains for each row, column, and square can be pre-calculated and stored in a map for quick lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have at least two options:

1- [Visitor Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/visitor-design-pattern)
This pattern is useful if you want to execute operations over an object without changing it. You can define an object for each cell in sudoku and let it be visited by a predefined Visitor. For doing so, you can, for instance, recursively find the next object in a predefined list(map) of objects and then execute the operation you want. A good option is to apply it in combination with [Iterator Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/iterator-design-pattern).

2- [Chain of Responsibility](https://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern)
This pattern is useful if you want that each cell execute the operation and have the control over the algorithm. You should create the chained structure and after the current cell executes the "compare values" operation, the chain is recursively called performing this verification.

As I said, both are useful if you want to "invert" the Observer behavior.

Comment: Visitor Pattern is used to achieve double dispatch. It makes no sense when there is only one concrete type, i.e. every box in the puzzle is the same.

Comment: @jaco0646, Chain of Responsibility may fall in the same problem: do not be fully utilized depending on the box type and evaluation function. The point asked was an approach that works in a different "direction" when compared to Observer Pattern. I think those ones achieved the goal